# blender python, create armature and assign an existing action

Tags: python, animation

I got a complex armature in a model. This armature has transform constraints to another armature etc...
Now, I am in this situation:

1. I have to create another armature object from scratch using a script.
2. Bake all the transforms to an action for example, effectively "baking" all sorts of constraints on those bones for a frame range.
3. Apply and play this "clean" action animation on this new "clean" armature. We need to have an armature playing the action (I mean no mesh, skin nor vertex groups etc..)

So I am doing something like this so far:

```py
bpy.ops.armature_add()
new_arm = bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active
...
editb=new_arm.data.edit_bones
for bone in other_arm.pose.bones:
    nbone = editb.new(bone.name)
    nbone.head = bone.head
    nbone.matrix = bone.matrix
    ...

action_obj = <How do we bake the animation to an action or something else "transferable" here>

new_arm.animation_data_create()
new_arm.animation_data.action = action_obj
# now when playing got lots of artifacts though
```

I assumed actions can be applied to other objects... I used this nicely in the past.

I thought this new feature for "baking the animation" would remove constraints but it doesnt work for all bones for some reason... so, I imagine this is an obvious approach but I couldn't get it to work just using plain blender ui, some bones work and others dont work... so I don't feel confident to use it in code (I think the command its bpy.ops.graph.bake()). Maybe this long question can be reduced to how to use this baking feature? (I tried with different options but no luck... besides I read of people having "unsolvable" issues with it)

Ok, here you have this.
I hope I explained the case clearly, I am happy to elaborate my question in any case.
I would like to hear your opinion, if I am missing something obvious or you recommend a different approach...

if you made it this far, thanks for your help already.

Comment: We will need to add animations to armatures as well. Did you get further with this? Perhaps look at the glTF addon?  IDK!